# Fail2ban bot search failregex mismatch error log format

Tags: fail2ban

I want to ban the following type bot search. But the default *nginx-botsearch.conf* not matching this error log.

```
2019/04/19 12:42:22 [error] 1193#1193: *6 open() "/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/.well-known/dnt-policy.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 184.0.77.164, server: domain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/dnt-policy.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

Then I modified default failregex as bellow. But it's not matching the above fail log.

```
failregex = ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/".*?
```

I'm not able to figure out which part cause this error. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo at the end:

```
request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/".*?
```

This does not make any sense. Why would you escape one `"` but not the other, and have two quantifiers following each other? I believe this is what you meant to write:

```
request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/.*\"
```

With this change, it does match your example log entry. Next time, use a visual regex editor (there are a few web-based ones), it will save you so much time.